# How can I add a query parameter using Elasticsearch RestHighLevelClient?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

How can I add a query parameter using Elasticsearch RestHighLevelClient?

For example:

```
/_search/q=style:SB
```

I do not see the option in the `SearchRequest` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't add query parameters in **RestHighLevelClient** because its main goal is to expose API specific methods, that accept request objects as an argument and return response objects.

As **RestHighLevelClient** is built on top of Low Level REST Client, you can use it to add the query parameters.

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
        RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
```

Use this to get the low level client from RestHighLevelClient:

```
RestClient lowLevelClient = client.getLowLevelClient();
```

The Low level REST client has a method performRequest which accepts the query parameter:

```
lowLevelClient.performRequest(method, endpoint, params, entity, null);
```

method description:

```
public Response performRequest(String method, String endpoint, Map<String, String> params,
                                   HttpEntity entity, HttpAsyncResponseConsumerFactory httpAsyncResponseConsumerFactory,
                                   Header... headers) throws IOException {
        SyncResponseListener listener = new SyncResponseListener(maxRetryTimeoutMillis);
        performRequestAsync(method, endpoint, params, entity, httpAsyncResponseConsumerFactory, listener, headers);
        return listener.get();
    }
```

Javadoc: [performRequest](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/6.0.1/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClient.html#performRequest-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-org.apache.http.HttpEntity-org.apache.http.Header...-)

Comment: This method deprecated, at least in 6.4.3 client and up - https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/6.4.3/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClient.html#performRequest(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,org.apache.http.Header...)